# Google Maps import

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, import, google-maps

I've been trying to port some 5000 entries of a CSV into ExpressionEngine using the Google Map Import utility.

However, I only seem to be able to import if I segment my CSV into multiple parts.

The CSV itself is fine as I tried importing with Datagrab as well and it went without a hitch.

After setting up the Google Map Import, when I select the schema, select my CSV and then hit `add to pool` the page refreshes but nothing happens. No warning, error or anything.

Segmenting the CSV into multiple chunks seems convoluted and from background reading shouldn't be necessary for what is a relatively small dataset.

I'm running 2.8.1 and the latest version of the addon.

Have emailed support as well but wondered if anyone else has had anything similar?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?